# Upgradeable Proxy Pattern - using from other contract

Tags: contract-development, solidity-0.8.x, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I am trying to use the upgradable proxy pattern in mi contracts and at the end, i can call the setters ok, but the getters are not working.
I have Clients that has a count value storage, a getCount and setCount. The proxyClients that delegate all calls to Clients, and the Organizations contract that uses Clients (whith address the proxy, so it really uses the proxyClients that then calls Clients).
I deploy everything, and try it on remix, and fron ORganizations i can call the setClientsCount Ok (and see the change in the client contract), but the getClientsCount show me error.

This are the contracts:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract ProxyClients {

    bytes32 private constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT =
        bytes32(uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1);
    bytes32 private constant ADMIN_SLOT =
        bytes32(uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.admin")) - 1);

    constructor() {
        _setAdmin(msg.sender);
    }
    function _getAdmin() private view returns (address) {
        return StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(ADMIN_SLOT).value;
    }

    function _setAdmin(address _admin) private {
        require(_admin != address(0), "admin = zero address");
        StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(ADMIN_SLOT).value = _admin;
    }
    function upgradeTo(address _implementation) public ifAdmin {
        _setImplementation(_implementation);
    }
    function _getImplementation() private view returns (address) {
        return StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value;
    }

    function _setImplementation(address _implementation) private {
        require(_implementation.code.length > 0, "implementation is not contract");
        StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value = _implementation;
    }

    function _delegate(address _implementation) internal virtual {
        emit Log("Entro delegate");

        assembly {
            let _target := sload(0)
            calldatacopy(0x0, 0x0, calldatasize())
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), _implementation, 0x0, calldatasize(), 0x0, 0)
            returndatacopy(0x0, 0x0, returndatasize())
            switch result case 0 {revert(0, 0)} default {return (0, returndatasize())}
        }
    }

     fallback() external payable{
        emit Log("Entro a fallback");

        _delegate(_getImplementation());

    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit Log("Entro a receive");

        _delegate(_getImplementation());

    }
}

library StorageSlot {
    struct AddressSlot {
        address value;
    }

    function getAddressSlot(
        bytes32 slot
    ) internal pure returns (AddressSlot storage r) {
        assembly {
            r.slot := slot
        }
    }
}
_______________

contract Clients {
    uint public count;

    function inc() public {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    function getCount() public pure returns (uint) {
        return 3;
    }

    function setCount(uint _count) public  {
        count = _count;
    }
}
_______________

pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "./Clients.sol";



contract Organizations {

    Clients clientsContract;


    string public name;

    function nameHello() external {
        name = "hello";
    }

    function nameBye() external {
        name = "bye";
    }

    function getClientsCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return clientsContract.getCount();
    }

    function setClientsCount(uint _clientCount) public{
        clientsContract.setCount(_clientCount);
    }

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function setReferences(
        address[] memory references
    ) public {
        clientsContract = Clients(references[0]);
    }


}
```